# Suppress code in NBConvert? IPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have figured out how to suppress large code blocks from showing up in final NB convert (PDF) output.

By putting the LaTex command in a "raw cell before the code I don't want to have in the final output

```
\iffalse
```

Followed By this at the end In a raw cell

```
\fi
```

But That still leaves me with some ugly code when I need to show figures and the like and while the base purpose of the notebook is to show code with results, sometimes for a non tech audience we only need the output.. Any Ideas?

Somewhat related if anyone is inspired.. any way to include python variables in the markdown cells so one could have dynamic text with calculated result? Sorry for a second issue but I'm not sure I want to ask this one separately for some strange reason.

Comment: Do you want to suppress only some of the code blocks or all?

Comment: Regarding the second issue (called *Literate programming*), there was a PR by @Carreau see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2592 but there was no decision on the syntax (yet).

Comment: I could live with either suppressing all or selectively... Selective is nicer but in fact the current case would be fine with all..

Comment: Shame the pull request seems stuck in limbo as close as it seemed to implemented...

Comment: The PR will be reoppened (it's mine) we need some architecture fix first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To suppress the code cells (only input) a custom template can be used. Similar as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19385350/2870069), a template e.g. *latex_nocode.tplx* has to be created (in the working directory) with the following content (for IPython 1.x)

```
((*- extends 'latex_article.tplx' -*))
% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))
```

use this template like
`ipython nbconvert --to=latex --template=latex_nocode.tplx --post=pdf file.ipynb`

Maybe I should add that this way the input block is simply replaced by a blank block (actually a latex comment that input cells are disabled).
When checking the predefined latex templates, the individual blocks (code, markdown, heading, etc) can be identified and a respective custom templates can be set-up to style the output as desired.

### Edit

as user1248490 pointed out since IPython 2.0 the latex templates to be extended are called
`article.tplx`, `report.tplx` or `base.tplx`. Hence the example from above should look like

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))
% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))
```

Comment: With IPython 2, this worked using `article.tplx` instead of `latex_article.tplx`.

Comment: Argument ```--to=latex``` was deprecated in favour of ```--to=pdf```. It accepts the same options, so appart from changing that and removing the ```--post=pdf``` argument, the command remains the same.

Comment: This works for me but unfortunately also blocks all the outputs...does the disable input cells actually disable them from being executed and producing outputs?

Answer (score 5):

If you've stumbled here from IPython 3.2.0 on Windows on Anaconda (I can't see why this wouldn't work on unix systems or on a regular ipython install, but I have not tested those scenarios myself) - this method is what's worked for me.  Use TorokLev's latex template (say pdf_nocode.tplx) and then create a python file (say pdf_nocode.py) and paste the following:

```
c = get_config()

#Export all the notebooks in the current directory to the sphinx_howto format.
c.NbConvertApp.notebooks = ['*.ipynb']
c.NbConvertApp.export_format = 'pdf'
c.TemplateExporter.template_path = ['.', r"C:\your\path\to\tplx\folder"]
c.Exporter.template_file = 'pdf_nocode'
```

Finally, your command will be:

```
ipython nbconvert --to=pdf --config C:\your\path\to\pdf_nocode.py
```

This will also generate the images as support files, if you want to suppress that output (I use mostly plots so this may not work for everyone), you can either modify

```
site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py
```

by adding this code:

```
...
def from_notebook_node(self, nb, resources=None, **kw):
...
        # convert output extension to pdf
        # the writer above required it to be tex
        resources['output_extension'] = '.pdf'

        #The following suppresses the support files, so you may
        #end up removing other useful files you wanted to include
        del resources['outputs']
...
```

or by subclassing PDFExporter from pdf.py and adding your exporter in exporter_map to:

```
site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters\export.py
```

If you subclass it does have a side benefit of you being able to add your own entry to the notebook menu in:

```
site-packages\IPython\html\static\notebook\js\menubar.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrections to the answer above:

1) Correct document class name in the latex file above

You should change the line

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))
% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))
```

2) Add local directory to nbconvert config as

`sudo gedit /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/tests/dotipython/profile_default/ipython_nbconvert_config.py`

add a line 
`c.TemplateExporter.template_path = ['.']`
to the file

3) Call the converter as

`ipython nbconvert --to=pdf --template=latex_nocode.tplx tested_notebook.ipynb`

or if you want to execute all cells for a report for example:

`ipython nbconvert --to=pdf --template=latex_nocode.tplx --ExecutePreprocessor.enabled=True tested_notebook.ipynb`