# NBConvert PDF/Latex page formatting IPython

Tags: latex, ipython

Got some good advice on suppressing code and other items on NBConvert output,, Here [Suppress code in NBConvert? IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524554/suppress-code-in-nbconvert-ipython/19528147#19528147) 
BUT: now It seems I need to change top and bottom margins And I can see that it seems that it may be set in the sphnix template, (if I even know where it is), which I don't want to mess with but I cannot figure out how to edit the Latex output to get at the margins I attempted to place this in the import headers

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

But nothing happened.. I know squat about latex I am using the TexStudio package to modify the Latex output of NB convert, but at this point I don't see something to modify for margins...

I'm trying to touch up some page flow issues involving placement of output graphs that are just too big so I end up with big ugly blank spots,, pretty sure that if I can get at the margins I can...

Comment: I guess directly edit the resulting .tex file and don't try to change this via a custom nbconvert template?

Comment: The strange thing is that I cannot see anyway to get the Tex file to affect top or bottom margins... I thought the \usepackage line would do it but nope..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the margins using your proposed code, you have to put this line after the other inputs, e.g. about line 71. If you put it at the top, it will be overridden by another call. With my notebook this works fine.

I'm pretty sure you know you can specify different margins using
`\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}`
see e.g. [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Btw. be aware that the sphinx based templates are removed in current master. The new templates are much more customizable and remove some issues due to the mdframed packages ([GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3866))