# Expand variables in Markdown cells of ipython-notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Inside a markdown cell in an ipython-notebook I'd like to be able to expand variables automatically. Can this be done?

As an example, consider the following code

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from markdown import markdown

base_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
markdown_string = "Two categories at [stackoverflow]({0}) are "\
                  "[ipython-notebook]({0}questions/tagged/ipython-notebook) and "\
                  "[matplotlib]({0}questions/tagged/matplotlib).".format(base_url)
HTML("<p>{}</p>".format(markdown(markdown_string)))
```

This produces the output cell with the links correct, all relative to `base_url`, as

> Two categories at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) are [ipython-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython-notebook) and [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib).

What I would like is to be able to directly type the markdown into the cell, referencing a pre-defined variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `IPython.core.display.HTML` before, always ended up rolling my own object with `_repr_html_`.

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18878083/2870069 some comments are also given here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19524554/2870069

Comment: @Jakob is correct - what I wanted is exactly in the first question, which gives me the answer I was expecting.

Comment: @Ian your approach (writing markdown as pyout) is currently a good thing! If you use a custom exporter template you could at least create documents (html, latex, ..) looking exactly the way you are aiming at. However, the notebook itself would still be cluttered :(

Comment: @Ian in the meantime an ipython extension has arrived which provides the desired functionality. See the updated answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328029/2870069) question.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's not possible yet to do with a real Markdown cell, you can easily create a magic to get the same effect.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.magic import (Magics, magics_class,  cell_magic)

@magics_class
class MarkdownMagics(Magics):

    @cell_magic
    def markdown(self, line, cell):
        from IPython.core.display import HTML
        from markdown import markdown

        vars = line.split()

        d = {}
        for k, v in self.shell.user_ns.items():
            if k in vars:
                d[k] = v

        return HTML("<p>{}</p>".format(markdown(cell.format(**d))))

get_ipython().register_magics(MarkdownMagics)
```

Set some Variables

```py
foo = 1
bar = 2
```

Then call the magic, with arguments being the variables you want to take from the namespace.

```
%%markdown foo bar

Substitute _{foo}_ and *{bar}*
```

Answer (score 7):

As @Jakob answered in the comments, the easiest way to accompish this is to install the [python-markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/usability/python-markdown) IPython notebook extension, as described on the [wiki page](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/python-markdown).

You can then access your variables in markdown by surrounding them with curly brackets:

Python cell:

```
x = 1000
```

Markdown cell:

```
Insert variable contents here -> {{x}}.
```

The markdown cell gets parsed as:

```
Insert variable contents here -> 1000.
```