# Inline python in markdown with iPython Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to call bits of python inside a markdown cell? For example I might like to write

```
Above there is a plot of {{numVars}} variables
```

In a markdown cell, so that when I change something elsewhere I don't need to go back and update the descriptive text of things.

It needn't be statements, although that would be useful (`len(x) + 5`), variables would be enough to make a big difference!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21364102/2870069 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18878083/2870069

Comment: The current state of this issue can be read about [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2958#issuecomment-36393701)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use variables on an IPython notebook markup cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878083/can-i-use-variables-on-an-ipython-notebook-markup-cell)