# How to make nice pdf out of jupyter file?

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am supposed to create pdf documents that contain math expression and graph images.

Until now my work flow was using matlab to draw the plots, export them into jpg, put them into OpenOffice / Word document describe how I get those plots trough math equations and finally export to pdf.

Recently I have found [julia](http://julialang.org/) ( replacement for matlab ) and [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) ( replacement for Word ).

Jupyter is awesome but the export to PDF is lacking some features :

1. Hide code cell. ( I don't want to show the code I used to generate those graphs. )
2. Hide output of code cell. ( I don't want to show output of `using Plots; plotlyjs()` )
3. Hide the `IN [...]` and `OUT [...]` annotations.
4. Increase space size between lines.

I hope there is some easy way to do this. Otherwise I will have to go back to Word and Matlab.

Thank you!

Comment: Btw isn't there something like `\```latex ... ``` `? `$ ... $` is good for one line but not for multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider investing some time learning how to use the [nbconvert tool](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that comes with jupyter notebook. It supports multiple output formats including PDF and also supports custom templates. For example see [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524554/suppress-code-in-nbconvert-ipython) for an example of hiding code input and only showing output.